# Drools Exception Jitting

Tags: drools

We have problems with exception jitting in our application using Drools 7.10.0. Were getting the following log warnings multiple times on runtime:

```
[MvelConstraint]; ___; Exception jitting: ($n > 0 && true) || (!($n > 0) && !true) This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
[MvelConstraint]; ___; Exception jitting: ($n > 0 && false) || (!($n > 0) && !false) This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
```

We've double checked all our Drools conditions, but cannot find this one. We have build a process to log all conditions into a .txt file while building our application. Still not found this rule. 
Is it possible, this condition is part of the Drools engine files itself?